# How to call local WCF service from webpage?

Tags: wcf, web-services, web-applications, network-programming

I'm developing a webpage that is supposed to consume WCF webserice that is located on client's computer. First, user installs some software that hosts WCF service on his computer, then he'll view my webpage which is supposed to call the WCF service. Do you have any idea how to do it without having to use AtiveX and IE?

Comment: That is extremelly bad design. What should local service do?

Answer (score 0):

Add your wcf service as service reference to your web project. You have to specify the url of your wcf service. A clientproxyclass will be generated for you. In your webpages or whathever you can create a instance of this proxyclass and just code what you want.